# Algorithm for finding empty cell around desired position in a grid

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization, grid

I will describe my problem using the attached image :

[image: grid]

The green block is the starting position of my game entity. Next I'd like to move it to the position marked by the orange square. But at the same time, I assume that levitation is not possible or/& this block is a wall. In either case going there is not possible. So I need to figure out a way of finding the first available place (as close to the orange square as possible) for my entity to move (in this case it would be either the top of the grey column or point two rows beneath the orange square).

I have a 2d array describing the grid, where `1` is a wall and `0` is empty space.

```
data = [
    [1,1,1,1,...],
    [1,0,0,0,0,...],
    [1,0,0,...],
    ...
]
```

I was thinking about solution in this way (where for example I can check at `1.` if beneath my cell is floor and end the algo, or continue if not to cell `2.`) but I can't think of a way of doing this efficiently (and easily).

[image]

Does anyone has any ideas how to tackle this ? I'm not really sure what algo should I ask google for :)

Comment: how will dijkstra be of any help if I don't really have the target specified as it may be different than the initial one ?

Comment: Assignment for Algorithms 101?

Comment: @alex23 but if orange point turns out not to be available ? I need to find a point as close as possible that is not a wall, is not in the middle of air etc. I've got A* already implemented for traveling, but in this case only the destination of the travel is troublesome.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for Q-learning algorithms. This is a form of reinforcement learning. Here's one http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SARSA

Basically you run the simulation between source and destination multiple times and each time it gets close and closer to discovering the goal.

Comment: thanks, I'll check this one. But don't you think that AI algo is a bit overcomplicated for this case ?

Comment: Alternatively you can use [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) for every point around the orange block and select the one with least cost.

Comment: It starts to be promlematic if none of the cells touching the orange one is available. Then we need to look further away.

Comment: Yeah I see. Sarsa will give you benefit value (q value) for EVERY square in the vicinity of the goal. Some parameters you will need to modify is the amount of greedy moves you make vs. random moves

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Cellular Automata for your case, if it is worth the trouble. It is not AI per se, easy to implement and you can replace A* as well as the final position finding problem using one logic.

Consider the eight neighbourhood cells around the game entity. Each cell can be free or blocked (0 or 1). There will be 2^8 combinations of the neighbourhood, but you may or may not have to use that many rules for the CA.

Try looking into this: http://www.cs.sun.ac.za/rw711/2012term1/documents/CABehringPathPlanning.pdf
they implemented CA for path planning in robotics, you can tweak it to suit your need.

The advantage is, with proper rule set, your CA will terminate only when the game entity has reached the appropriate position around the goal (closest to the goal and not levitating).

You can also implement multiple rule sets on the system, thereby making it more robust.